# Query in SQLite for merging two tables

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

```
TableMain
Task_Id  Task   DateTime        Repetition  Snooze_Time
1        Task1  2020-3-14 11:43 0           0

TableRoutine
Task_Id  Task   DateTime        Repetition  Snooze_Time
1        Task2  2020-3-14 14:55 0           0
```

I need result like this:

```
Task    DateTime
Task1   2020-3-14 11:43
Task2   2020-3-14 14:55
```

I found query which merge the two tables but it creates 4 columns!!!
But I need data into only two rows as shows so is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like you were using a `JOIN`, when in fact you need a `UNION`:

```
SELECT Task, DateTime
FROM TableMain
UNION
SELECT Task, DateTime
FROM TableRoutine
```

`UNION` will remove duplicate rows; if you want them in the output, change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thanks for this fast and accurate answer.I was searching for like 2 hours and you just give me solution in just 10 seconds. Again thanks to you and stackoverflow!!!

Comment: Oh yeah!! Thx for that too. I checked your answer.